# IcoMoon icons not working in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, font-face, haslayout

I'm using IcoMoon icons on my site and while they work perfectly in all modern browsers they don't work at all in [Internet Explorer 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7) and show as little boxes in [Internet Explorer 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8). The CSS is as follows which is from IcoMoon apart from the relative path to the font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url ('../fonts/icomoon.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant:normal;
}
```

I'm using the data-icon attribute (e.g. `<li data-icon="&#xe003;"><a href`, etc.) to display the icon in my navigation.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Answer on your problem is in your question: IE8 ;)

Comment: could you enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

When you generate your icons on iconmoon, go to preferences and check support for ie6 and ie7
[image: check this box]

You will get a seperate ie7 folder inside your fonts, then use something like this in your head.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie7/ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

There are two files you can use either ie7.css or ie7.js

Answer (score 0):

I have been trawling the Internet looking for the answer to this self-same dilemma as I use [Joomla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla) 3x with [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) and IcoMoon. It too doesn't work in Internet Explorer 7 or Internet Explorer 6. According to this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576616/font-face-being-ignored-by-ie7) your issue could be:

1. Giving the offending elements hasLayout by assigning `zoom:1` through CSS (Internet Explorer proprietary).
2. The `@font-face` declaration is different for Internet Explorer 7 (outlined in the last response to the question).
3. It could also be that your font type is not properly supported.

And I think @Damonsson is referring to Internet Explorer's startling ability to never do anything as expected... or required... or even pleadingly, sobbingly begged to do.

Happy hunting!

Answer (score -1):

The following might help you out. PPseudo elements aren't supported prior to Internet Explorer 8. I am trying to figure out the Internet Explorer 8 dilemma myself...

http://icomoon.io/#docs/lte-ie7

Comment: So you go around correcting typos and you end up making one yourself. 'PPseudo' isn't a word.