# IcoMoon display issue in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-face, icon-fonts

I have a problem with my icomoon font in Chrome with that icons are sometimes not shown. I don't get the font-missing empty rectangle "fallback".

When I select the element with an icon it will appear, so a repaint will fix it. But forcing a repaint is a terrible solution...

The only solution I find regarding buggy iconfonts in Chrome is to use PUA codes, but I already do that.

My CSS for icons:

```
.icon-back-in-time-mirror:before {
    content: "\e613";
}

.icon {
    position: relative;
}

.icon:before {
    position: absolute;
    height: 22px;
    margin: -11px 0 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 22px;
    display: block;
    speak: none;
}
```

The `@font-face` rules

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:url('/gui/css/fonts/icomoon.eot?-cpkbjx');
  src:url('/gui/css/fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix-cpkbjx') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/gui/css/fonts/icomoon.woff?-cpkbjx') format('woff'),
    url('/gui/css/fonts/icomoon.ttf?-cpkbjx') format('truetype'),
    url('/gui/css/fonts/icomoon.svg?-cpkbjx#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Possible related question (if the problem is confined to Chrome 33): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011139/google-fonts-are-not-rendering-on-google-chrome/22025804#22025804

Comment: I didn't have the issue when I used the Entypo icon-font, and no issue with the Roboto google font that I also use. Only the icomoon font are behaving this way. If possible I'd like a solution that don't force a repaint.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I can help, then. Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571588/some-icomoon-icons-wont-display?rq=1

Comment: @Megan I've tested the site in Chrome 35 canary and the issue seems to be gone. So your first answer were probably right. I don't think the site will be launched before Chrome 34 is released, so I think I'll let the issue be. Thanks for the help