# How to display rupee symbol in IE 7?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, magento

I use

```
&#8377;
```

to display ₹ in our website.

it is supported in all major web browsers, but not in IE 7, so how can I display ₹ symbol in IE7.

web site is built on Magento and I gave the symbol as

```
<currency type="INR">
    <displayName>Indian Rupee</displayName>
    <displayName count="one">Indian rupee</displayName>
    <displayName count="other">Indian rupees</displayName>
    <symbol>&#8377;</symbol>
</currency>
```

in MAGENTO_ROOT/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml

Comment: It's not so much a matter of IE 7 not supporting it, but rather that IE 7 does not load *fonts* that contain the symbol. You might want to use an Embedded OpenType font which supports it (note: [IE before 9 is very particular about `@font-face` declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576616/font-face-being-ignored-by-ie7)) and apply that font to elements which contain the rupee symbol.

Comment: By the way, if you can consistently put the symbol in its own element, you could choose to use [this ugly hack](http://blog.blueornate.com/how-to-get-rupee-symbol-in-html/) ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indian rupee symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741931/indian-rupee-symbol)

Comment: Search for previous questions on rupee.

Comment: The duplicate you mention has a poor quality answer. You can definitely fix this with a trick.

Answer (score 0):

[FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/inr/) supports IE-7 and these are literally awesome. They scale well.
Definitely worth a shot. Hope it works for you.